# Select <a> tag where <input> is inside with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to apply `style="text-decoration: none;"` to all of my `<a>` tags that contain a `<input>` tag. Since I can't do this with CSS, I thought jQuery could help me find where this case is, and apply the style.

Example:

`<a href="http://www.google.com"><input type="button" value="Click here to go to Google!" /></a>`

**I know `.css('text-decoration', 'none')` applys the CSS, but how can I find the tags?**

Comment: Did you consider adding an event handler to the button instead that navigates?

Comment: Buttons and other interactive content are [not allowed](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) inside `<a>` elements. Use an `<a>` or a button, but not both.

Comment: I do have that in some cases, but these buttons were already written, and there are a number of them, so it's too time consuming to change them all (which is why I'm using jQuery to apply the style instead of going to each one and applying it). And in fact, for these links to work with IE7, the `<a>` tag has an `onclick="location.href='http://www.google.com'"` because otherwise IE7 won't follow the link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`:has`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector:

```
$("a:has(input)").css("text-decoration", "none");
```

or the [`.has`](http://api.jquery.com/has/) method:

```
$("a").has("input").css("text-decoration", "none");
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vttw8/)

Answer (score 4):

If you only want those that are direct parents, you can use

```
$("input").parent("a");
```

If you want the nearest ancestor, you can use

```
$("input").closest("a");
```

and if you want all ancestors, you can use:

```
$("input").parents("a");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('a:has(input)')
```

or

```
$('input').parents('a')
```

Comment: Should probably be noted that these two are not equivalent.  `:has` would be the same as `parents`.  The outcome with nested elements would be different.  Probably not a concern when used with `a` tags but still worth noting.

Answer (score 3):

There are (at least) two ways to achieve this:

```
$('a').has('input').css('text-decoration', 'none');
$('a:has(input)').css('text-decoration', 'none');
```